# How to set WaitCursor cursor over disabled panel in WinForms

Tags: winforms, panel

I'm trying to do this

```
panel.Enabled = false; // to disable all controls on panel at once
panel.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

and debugger shows that panel.Cursor is WaitCursor, but when I move a mouse over the panel, cursor is still Arrow.

```
panel.Update(); panel.Refresh(); // does not help
```

So, how to fix it?

Comment: By design, "disabled" does not mean "wait".  Set the form's Cursor property instead.

Comment: I didn't say it does. But a mouse over disabled panel is always arrow, even though its property Cursor = WaitCursor. Setting form's cursor doesn't help and, more over, it can be wrong in some scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

A disabled control will not receive Windows Messages.  Easiest is to keep it enabled and handle "Disabled" a different way.

An alternative for your specific need is to add the code below on to the button's parent - you can optimize the routine to call only when changes are needed.

```
        this.MouseMove += (s, a) =>
                              {
                                  if (button2.Bounds.Contains(a.Location))
                                      this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                                  else
                                      this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                              };
```